# What is the author trying to say in Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> The most amazing thing to J.K. Rowling is that Harry Potter has continued to be a huge success throughout the seven books, and that the passion never seems to die out. J.K. Rowling feared that she would be a complete failure, and after the first book was not sure she could write the others with the whole world looking over her shoulder. **Yet magic is something that sparks imagination and curiosity in the young and the old.** People from around the world connect to J.K. Rowling's characters and their magical world. J.K. Rowling's life experiences gave her the background to create the world of Harry Potter that has become important for people of all ages and circumstances.

I cannot understand what the author is trying to say here:

- Yet magic is something that sparks imagination and curiosity in the young and the old.

Comment: Would you understand it better if it said "Magic sparks imagination and curiosity in the young and the old"?  Do you know what "sparks" means when it is used as a transitive verb?

Answer (score 1):

> [Spark](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/spark): (n) 3. anything that activates or stimulates; inspiration or catalyst. (v) 12. to kindle, animate, or stimulate (interest, activity, spirit, etc.):

"Spark" is literally a small, hot particle, but in the same way that a spark can start a fire, it can be used metaphorically to be something that *kindles* some desire or emotion or even an action.

> These bright students **have sparked** her enthusiasm for teaching.
>
> Resentment against the nobility had been simmering for a while among the people of France, but many consider the unjust dismissal of a popular government official to be the **spark** that ignited the French Revolution.

In this context the author says that her world, where magic is real, is of great interest to both young and old people.  It is successful because it inspires (sparks) imagination and curiosity in everyone.